# Align content of fixed positioned table-cell to the right side?

Tags: css

Is is possible to align to the right the content of a table-cell which has a fixed position?

Please check the demo below - Third box with the yellow color should stick to the right side of the white container which is responsive.

Please note that fixed positions and table-cell must be kept.

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 80%;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
.first {
  ;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: red;
}
.second {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.third {
  text-align: right;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="first">First</td>
        <td class="second">Second</td>
        <td class="third">Third</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you wrote that fixed positions have to remain, but fixed positioned table cells are an extremely strange concept, and I would expect that this looks different in every browser, since the position of a fixed positioned element usually is only related to the viewport (window), which is useless inside a table.

In the following solution I gave the first and third cell `width: 25%` to make their width independent from their contents and put their contents in `span` tags to make the text-aligning work without having the background color spread over the whole cell width. I hope this is useful for you.

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 80%;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
.first {
  width: 25%;
}
.first > span {
  background-color: red;
}
  .second {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.third {
  width: 25%;
  text-align: right;
}
.third > span {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="first"><span>First</span></td>
        <td class="second">Second</td>
        <td class="third"><span>Third</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Fixed position and table-cell are a must be for me because they are used for a header that changes to fixed and as it is right now, works fine in chrome, firefox and safari. For mobile devices browsers it doesn't matter because the layout changes.